# Converting jQuery to JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following jQuery code for my navigation responsive that I need to convert to regular vanilla Javascript. I was trying to understand how does `removeAttr` works as well as children.

Is there anyone there who knows how to convert the following code to pure JavaScript?

```js
let responsiveMenu = function() {
  var menuType = 'desktop';
  
  $(window).on('load resize', function() {
    var currMenuType = 'desktop';
    if (matchMedia('only screen and (max-width: 991px)').matches) {
      currMenuType = 'mobile';
    }

    if (currMenuType !== menuType) {
      menuType = currMenuType;
      if (currMenuType === 'mobile') {
        var $mobileMenu = $('#mainnav').attr('id', 'mainnav-mobi').hide();
        var hasChildMenu = $('#mainnav-mobi').find('li:has(ul)');
        $('#header #site-header-inner').after($mobileMenu);
        hasChildMenu.children('ul').hide();
        hasChildMenu.children('a').after('<span class="btn-submenu"></span>');
        $('.btn-menu').removeClass('active');
      } else {
        var $desktopMenu = $('#mainnav-mobi').attr('id', 'mainnav').removeAttr('style');
        $desktopMenu.find('.submenu').removeAttr('style');
        $('#header').find('.nav-wrap').append($desktopMenu);
        $('.btn-submenu').remove();
      }
    }
  });

  $('.mobile-button').on('click', function() {
    $('#mainnav-mobi').slideToggle(300);
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });

  $(document).on('click', '#mainnav-mobi li .btn-submenu', function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul').slideToggle(300);
    e.stopImmediatePropagation()
  });
};
```

Comment: Just as an FYI as you're refactoring this anyway, I'd suggest you convert it to use CSS media queries instead of JS. CSS is designed for your exact purpose, and performs far better than JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a go with this

```js
const load_resize = function() {
  var currMenuType = 'desktop';
  if (matchMedia('only screen and (max-width: 991px)').matches) {
    currMenuType = 'mobile';
  }

  if (currMenuType !== menuType) {
    menuType = currMenuType;
    if (currMenuType === 'mobile') {
      const mobileMenu = document.getElementById('mainnav')
      mobileMenu.setAttribute('id', 'mainnav-mobi')
      mobileMenu.hidden = true;
      const hasChildMenu = document.getElementById('mainnav-mobi').querySelectorAll('li:has(ul)');
      const siteHead = document.getElementById('site-header-inner');
      siteHead.parentNode.insertAfter(mobileMenu, siteHead);
      hasChildMenu.forEach(li => li.querySelectorAll('ul').forEach(ul => ul.hidden = true));
      document.querySelectorAll('.btn-menu')
        .forEach(btnmenu => btnmenu.classList.remove('active'));
      hasChildMenu.forEach(li => li.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(a => {
        const span = document.createElement("span");
        span.classList.add("btn-submenu");
        a.parentNode.insertAfter(span, a);
      }));
    } else {
      const desktopMenu = document.getElementById('mainnav-mobi')
      desktopMenu.setAttribute('id', 'mainnav')
      desktopMenu.removeAttribute('style');
      desktopMenu.querySelectorAll('.submenu').forEach(sm => sm.removeAttribute('style'));
      document.getElementById('header').querySelectorAll('.nav-wrap').forEach(navwrap => {
        navwrap.appendChild(desktopMenu); // you need to clone here if more than one 
      });
      document.querySelectorAll('.btn-submenu').forEach(bsm => bsm.remove());
    }
  }
};

let responsiveMenu = function() {
  var menuType = 'desktop';

  window.addEventListener('load', load_resize)
  window.addEventListener('resize', load_resize)

  document.getElementById("container").addEventListener('click', function(e) { // a div container for mobile-button elements
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.classList.contains('mobile-button')) {
      document.getElementById('mainnav-mobi').classList.toggle("show") // slideToggle(300); needs a transition
      tgt.classList.toggle('active');
    }
  });

  document.getElementById("mainnav-mobi").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.classList.contains('btn-submenu')) {
      tgt.classList.toggle('active')
      tgt.nextElementSibling.slideToggle(300);
      e.stopImmediatePropagation()
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Checking this now.

Comment: Why do you use $ here instead of regular const var

Comment: theres an error on VS code saying that its expecting comma or colon right around here:  `const desktopMenu = document.getElementById('mainnav-mobi');
      desktopMenu.setAttribute('id', 'mainnav');
      desktopMenu.removeAttribute('style');`

Comment: I missed a few }) and ) - updated

Comment: Added the code on my index.html down the body part but it did not work. I am trying my best to atleast workaround the jQuery code here: https://jsfiddle.net/805u3g7b/

Comment: Ok, I have done enough. You can see what I did with some of the constructs. It would be better to rewrite from scratch since I already had to unwrap some jQuery into something that might not be needed when there is only one element and $(selector) will choose any amount of elements

Comment: Thank you. yeah. Anyway took your answer still.

Answer (score 0):

JQUERY

```
$(el).removeAttr('tabindex');
```

IE8+

```
el.removeAttribute('tabindex');
```

Stolen from the (very good) Page

http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: How do I convert the jQuery snippet above to vanilla JS?